# Merge multiple dataframes without common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets.

```
dict1 =pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['A','B','C','D'], 'Score' : [19,20,11,12]})
list1 =pd.DataFrame(['Math', 'English', 'History', 'Science'])
concat_data = pd.concat([dict1,list1])
```

output :

```
Name  Score        0
0    A   19.0      NaN
1    B   20.0      NaN
2    C   11.0      NaN
3    D   12.0      NaN
0  NaN    NaN     Math
1  NaN    NaN  English
2  NaN    NaN  History
3  NaN    NaN  Science
```

The output I am looking for:

```
Name  Score        0
0    A   19.0      Math
1    B   20.0      English
2    C   11.0      History
3    D   12.0      Science
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is pass the correct `axis`. The [default behavior for concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is `axis=0` which means the operation takes place index-wise or row-wise, while you are needing the operation to be performed column-wise:

> axis: {0/’index’, 1/’columns’}, default 0
>   The axis to concatenate along.

```
concat_data = pd.concat([dict1,list1],axis=1)
print(concat_data)
```

Outputs:

```
 Name  Score        0
0    A     19     Math
1    B     20  English
2    C     11  History
3    D     12  Science
```